# How can I join different segments of a list?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble in a school project because I don't know how to join elements of a list in segments. Here's an example: Let's say I have the following list:

```
list = ["T","h","i","s","I","s","A","L","i","s","t",]
```

How could I join this list so that the program outputs the following?:

```
Output: ["This","Is","A","List"]
```

Comment: Please, let us know what specifically are you having trouble with *in your code* so we can help you out

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `list` is your input, and without giving you the answer outright since it's a school project you should do yourself, here are some hints.

1. You'll want to check if a character is uppercase to know when the start of a word is. With python, you can use `isupper()` (ex: `'C'.isupper()` would return `True`).
2. Python strings are [iterable](https://www.techbeamers.com/iterate-strings-python/).
3. You can add a character to the end of a string using `+=` (ex: `myWord += 'a'`)
4. You can add a string to a list using `append` (ex: `myList.append(myWord)`)

Remember this is a learning experience and there's no real value to being given the answer outright, if that's what you were hoping for. Best of luck and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Just what I looked for. I spent some time on internet and found the isupper function but didn't know how to apply it in this scenario. I really like your philosophy and hope you keep helping people in the same way. Cheers and thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Sadly (or hopefully), python_learner wrote an answer a bit before me that incorporates everything I've said and gives you a possible answer outright. If you choose to use it, please make sure you understand every line, there are a few more advanced concepts in it. I appreciate your thanks and I hope you have fun programming

Comment: @OctaveL I post possible solutions in the hope people will understand and then re use, as opposed to cargo culting

Comment: @python_learner I get that mindset, but I feel like most people will simply copy and paste it without trying to understand it. Cargo culting is unavoidable if the answer is given away without first ensuring the one asking worked towards getting an answer beforehand, which wasn't clear here. I'd rather nudge in the right direction than give the answer, since I believe a lesson is more memorable when you reach it yourself than when you decipher someone else's

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this

```
import re

list = ["T","h","i","s","I","s","A","L","i","s","t",]
sep=[s for s in re.split("([A-Z][^A-Z]*)", ''.join(list)) if s]

print(sep)
```

Comment: That's a nice idea.